# Как получить сущность в jsp после неудачной валидации @Valid

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, view, jstl

Я использую аннотацию @Valid. Если я правильно понял, то эта аннотация должна не только валидировать сущность и заполнять BindingResult, но и автоматически ложить сущность в в модель jsp. Так вот. Как мне получить объект "employeeDto" в jsp?

```
@PostMapping
public ModelAndView create(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employeeDto") EmployeeDto employeeDto,
                           BindingResult bindingResult) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/action/employee/add_employee");
    //business logic

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        mav.addObject("entity", employeeDto); //Как избавиться от этой строчки?
        return mav;
    }

    //business logic
    return mav;
}
```

К примеру для получения ошибок я использую следующий код :

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="employeeDto">
    <s:set scope="page" var="errors" value="${errors}"/>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

Но как получить employeeDto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В jps можно достать request, а с ним уже открывается множество возможностей...:

```
<c:set var="entity" value="${pageContext.request.getAttribute(\"departmentDto\")}"/>
```